# Stream WAV files in browser without allowing download

Tags: php, html, audio, wav

I'm looking for a way to stream WAV files via a web interface without making the files downloadable (or at least hidden enough in the browser cache they can't easily be found by end users).

The files are recordings of calls within a call center, so due to legal requirements I need to log every time someone listens to a call. This means I must make sure that they can not easily download the file and listen to it later without it being logged.

The files are in g729 format on the server, but I can easily convert them on the fly to wav (or most other audio formats).

I've had a look into HTML5 audio and a few flash based players, but haven't as of yet found anything that doesn't expose the URL of the file.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think WAV is the best choice of format, it's uncompressed audio (i.e. massive amounts of data). I can't give you a specific answer, but look into using a flash object to play them. If you have to log playbacks, also might be worth generating one-time urls, so a user has to request the stream, and they can only stream using it once.

Comment: if its playing on on my speakers, i can record it.

Comment: Firefox + FlashGot extension = no media file is safe

Comment: Maybe far fetched: Have them listen to the recording from the same PBX, give them out a pin number that only works for a certain period and when entered plays back the specific recording. Or have your PBX on click call them back with the recording. If we are talking about Asterisk, both methods are easy to implement, and safer (It will also save you the g729 to wav conversion :)

Comment: Leigh - thanks for that. I can change the format, I've just been using WAV because it's easy to convert with asterisk. One time URLs is a good idea - thanks.

Dagon/Ronin - Thanks. I'm aware of this, however I think we're OK as long as we're taking reasonable measures to protect the files. It's only for staff members, not customers.

mobius - Good idea! I could simply have a pin generated that allows a single playback and have asterisk update the database. I've got a lot of AGI stuff already, so I think I could impliment that. Thanks, I'll play with that!

Comment: mobius - Can you please answer this as an answer instead of a comment? I want to mark this as solved by you!

Not exactly the solution I asked for, but a fantastic solution none the less.

The web page now has a "listen to recording" button. Onclick the user is asked to add a reason they are listening and who else will be listening. They are then given a unique 7 digit pin and an internal extension to call - the pin is stored in the database with the filename and reason.

Upon calling the extension they put in the PIN and the AGI script calls the file and marks the record as "listened"....

Comment: ... So that the pin can not be used again. This is a fantastic implementation and makes my life a LOT easier!

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting my comment above as an answer as requested by OP.

Maybe a far fetched solution but here goes:

Have them listen to the recording from the same PBX, give them out a pin number that only works for a certain period and when entered plays back the specific recording.

Or you could have your PBX on click, call them back with the recording.

If we are talking about Asterisk, both methods are easy to implement, and safer (It will also save you the g729 to wav conversion :)

(Btw on a side note, I have create a PHP library for Asterisk Manager API that you may find usefull. https://github.com/twmobius/Shift8 )

Cheers Andrew :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry - I've been away for a couple of days! Marked it as the answer now though. And thank you for writing Shift8! I actually used it when I was first using asterisk AGI. Unfortunately we had some strange custom needs, so I ended up writing my own library to work with our systems. But thank you!

Comment: @AndrewWhite Well shift8 will probably not be any use in terms of AGI, unless you use Async AGI. If you have any suggestions on improving the lib please open an issue on github :)

Comment: Hey mobius. Just wanted to follow up and let you know how helpful I found your answer to be. I developed something for this in-house and everyone loved it. It completely solves our needs. Thanks again!

Comment: @AndrewWhite Thank you for taking the time to write back with your results. I am happy to have helped :)